# Make a filter by words using an Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a code that allows me to filter a JSON object by both the name and the title. I have an array with a few words, I would like to make this same filter using an Array. I dont want use the input text, I need use the array.

I want to filter by each of the words in the array

```
$scope.arrayFilter=["is","mom","beautifull"];
```

[image]

Is it possible to perform this filter by default when I start my application ?. Thank you very much.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data ">
 <span ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:search"></span>
</li>

$scope.arrayFilter=["is","mom","beautifull"];
$scope.data = [{
    title: "mom is beautifull"
  }, {
    title: "my mom is great"
  }, {
    title: "I hate the matematics"
}];

.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
     return function(text, phrase) {
         if (phrase) text = text.replace(new RegExp('('+phrase+')', 'gi'),
            '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')

          return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the whole array to your filter and see if its there in the sentence, there is a small tweak you have to do here, put the array in the correct order to make the sentence matches. Otherwise this is not achievable with filter.

```
 $scope.arrayFilter=["mom","is","beautifull"];
```

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.arrayFilter=["mom","is","beautifull"];
$scope.data = [{
title: "mom is beautifull"
}, {
title: "my mom is great"
}, {
title: "I hate the matematics"
}];
});



app.filter('highlight', function($sce) {
return function(text, arrayFilter) {
    var stringToDisplay = '';
    angular.forEach(arrayFilter,function(key,value){
        if(text.includes(key)){
          stringToDisplay =  stringToDisplay.concat(key).concat(" ");
        }
    })
   stringToDisplay =  stringToDisplay.substring(0, stringToDisplay.length - 1);
   return $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(new RegExp(stringToDisplay, 'gi'), '<span class="highlightedText">$&</span>'));

}
});
```

```css
.highlightedText {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<li ng-repeat="item in data ">
    <span ng-bind-html="item.title | highlight:arrayFilter"></span>
  </li>
</body>
```

Comment: GREAT. If with a .push I add a new word to the array, will it be updated?. What is 'gi'. Thanks!

Comment: g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])

Comment: @yavg what happened ?

Comment: Always have to go in order the array? This does not fit my real problem. The words should be in any order and then mark them.